# Deploying and maintaining states of machine learning models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

Alright, so I am pretty new to Machine/Deep Learning world and getting my hands dirty on implementing algorithms but there are few gaps which I have and want to understand how the industry is doing this.

I am an experienced developer with an experience of five and a half years of application (Web and Mobile) development with complex use cases. I have detailed knowledge on how to take an application from development to production starting right from scratch.

While going through the tutorials and all of the documentation available online explaining how to develop the model locally which basically looks like a python script. This script takes some data in either the structured or unstructured way, preprocess the data and the train the model on the received data. All this is fine as there are a lot of documents, tutorials available online for this but no one explains how to take it to production and how to maintain it on the production.

I am yet to identify, how to push the model to production, also when the model is deployed on the production, from which data we should train the model on the server. Should it be the same data which we used locally on the machine or some other data? Also, when we make any changes to the model and redeploy it on the production, do we have to train the model again (as the model seems to be stateless and must storing all of the training results and finding on the memory). If it is true, then redeploying the model will bring downtime to the application during the time model is being trained on the server.

I bet industry must be handling all of this in some or the other way. I want to understand the whole process and if I can have references for the same it would be really great.

I am using `Tensorlfow`, `Scikitlearn` and other popular libraries for development.

Comment: Let me kindly remind you that SO is about *specific coding* questions, not about system design, deploying options, or external sources location & recommendations; specifically for the last part of your question (references), please do take some time to re-read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

this is just my take, and it may not be standard.

A model is just a model, you can save it to a file, it's just a file, you can make copies of it, there's nothing ezoteric about it.

One way of deploying is by exposing the `.predict()` method via some form of API. You can do this with your favorite web framework but since you're using `tensorflow` it's probably easier with flask/django.

Another thing is, in the event where you're not actually messing with the internals of layers is to just use `keras`, which is much more straightforward to use for the layman than `tensorflow` and it sits on top of `tensorflow` so you're using the same tech.

So how to handle retraining? Well ML is compute intensive only when training so you do that separately, take your trained model and plug it back into your API. Ideally this can be done without actually interrupting production, it's just a file that can be overwritten at the end of the day. There are subtleties of course but it should be pretty close to seamless.

As for continuing training after the fact, i would start with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708655/how-to-load-a-tensorflow-model-and-continue-training).

Comment: I kindly suggest you refrain from answering off-topic questions, as advised in the community guidelines - please see [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions), [“Why shouldn't I answer off-topic questions?” FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262573/why-shouldnt-i-answer-off-topic-questions-faq), and [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)